# Mysql speed up max() group by

Tags: group-by, max

I have an easy query for grouping rows which takes 0.0045 sec. for 300.000 rows

`SELECT cid FROM table GROUP BY cid`

When I add MAX() to query it takes 0.65 sec to return.

`SELECT MAX(id) id, cid FROM table GROUP BY cid`

How can I speed up this query? The query runs on my local host for testing. id = primary key and I have index on cid.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is the difference between the two queries:

- Your first query will never touch the table - it wil rely on the index only
- Your second query actually needs to hit all rows

So to get back to the more optimal first case, you need an index, that can provide both: grouping by cid and min/maxing id. You could try to achieve this by creating an index on (cid,id)

Comment: Thank you. I did what you told and added index on (cid,id) Now I have 3 indexes id(PK), (cid,id) and cid. The query now takes 0.0085 sec.
I have another question regarding your approach. Does id(PK) not work as an index here? Seperate cid index that I created earlier needed or useless? Thanks everyone.

Comment: the key on `id` may or may not be used (see EXPLAIN SELECT ...), but anyway it has to be queried twice for each cid. The composite key provides single-key lookup with excellent locality: entries you use will be close together, often in the same page, so no additional IO is required. The key on `cid` is not needed for this query - you should remove it, if no other queries rely on it, to speed up insert times

Comment: I understood what you mean. I will make another tests to see how it will perform. For `cid` key assuming that there is only one condition `where cid = 15;` `(cid,id)` is enough or should I keep `cid` too?

Comment: (Good) rule of thumb is: a composite index is a perfect replacement for its first part. So `(cid,id)` should be a perfect replacement of `cid` only. There may be edge cases with big tables and low RAM: The composite index can put less rows in one index page, so you need more index pages for lookup. This may slow down the use of a composite index a.o.t a single column index, but again: This is an edge case.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you suggest me any books or sources where can I study these kind of tips or rules of MySQL? Or mysql.com is my best friend?

Comment: Your best friend is to work with MySQL and get to learn its quirks and virtues hands-on. If you run into a quirk or problem, don't stop, if you made it go away - stop only, if you have completly understood it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep all the things you said in mind. Now let me do some tests to go deeper :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try adding a composite index on cid and id.  This could possibly replace the existing index on just cid.  I suggest you profile some typical queries to assess the impact of increasing the size of the existing index.  The composite index contains exactly the data required to satisfy the query, so should minimise the work required.

MySQL uses cost-based optimization.  The costing is based on the amount of i/o, hence if you can put in place an index on just the columns of interest this, should minimise i/o and lead to an optimal query.

Comment: I agree. Seems to me this is one of the few options. Another possibility would be to partition on cid; this could dramatically speed up the query if the number of distinct values in cid is quite small as compared to the total size of the table. With that partitioning in place, only an index on id would be required.

Answer (score 0):

See what mysql manual says about speeding up the max() , min() query

> MySQL uses indexes for these operations:
>
> To find the MIN() or MAX() value for a specific indexed column
>   key_col. This is optimized by a preprocessor that checks whether you
>   are using WHERE key_part_N = constant on all key parts that occur
>   before key_col in the index. In this case, MySQL does a single key
>   lookup for each MIN() or MAX() expression and replaces it with a
>   constant.

Comment: Seems this irrelevant for this particular query?