# SQLite - Selecting not indexed column in GROUP BY

Tags: sqlite

I have similar situation like question below.

[Mysql speed up max() group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309224/mysql-speed-up-max-group-by)

```
SELECT MAX(id) id, cid FROM table GROUP BY cid
```

To optimize above query (shown in the question), creating index(cid, id) does the trick.

However, when I add a column that is not indexed to SELECT, query speed drastically slows down.

For example,

```
SELECT MAX(id) id, cid, newcolumn FROM table GROUP BY cid
```

If I create index(cid, id, newcolumn), query time comes back to minimal. It seems I should index all the columns I select while using GROUP BY.

Is there any way other than indexing all the columns to be select?

Comment: Just for clarity, is the second query grouped by cid, newcolumn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all the columns used in the query are part of the index (which is then called a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx)), SQLite can get all values from the index and does not need to access the table itself.

When adding a column that is not indexed, each record must be looked up in both the index and the table.
Furthermore, the order of the records in the table is unlikely to be the same as the order in the index, so the table's pages are not read in order, and are read multiple times, which means that caching will not work as well.

The `newcolumn` values must be read from either the table or an index; there is no other mechanism to store data.

tl;dr: no